# Windows 11 keyboard layout does not match Language & Region keyboard settings

Tags: windows-11, keyboard-layout

I have following `Time & Language > Language & Region > Options > Keyboard settings` where I have two keyboards defined,

- Czech (QWERTY)
- United States-International

[image]

but in `Keyboard layout` I can see four of them

[image]

Why is this happening and how to solve it?